# Name of algorithm (or paper) that scikit-learn cluster.estimate_bandwidth() function implements for meanshift bandwidth selection

Tags: clustering, algorithms, scikit-learn

Can someone tell me the name of the algorithm (or paper)
that [sklearn.cluster.estimate_bandwidth](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.estimate_bandwidth.html#sklearn.cluster.estimate_bandwidth) implements and is used by the meanshift algorithm implemented in Scikit-Learn to automatically select its bandwidth parameter?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
From the link to the code given by Franck, it seems that the bandwidth sigma is estimated for a set of feature vectors X using the average of the furthest distance between vectors in X to their k nearest neighbors. These vectors (whose pairwise distance we are considering) are either sampled randomly or computed using all the vectors in X in batches, depending on the parameters given.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the name of a function; it is probably best addressed to the developers of the software, or to a list on that software

Comment: I'm not looking for the name of the function. I'm looking for the name of the *algorithm* that the function implements.

Comment: Hmm. OK. I withdraw my objection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/mean_shift_.py#L4

> Dorin Comaniciu and Peter Meer, "Mean Shift: A robust approach toward
>       feature space analysis". IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and
>       Machine Intelligence. 2002. pp. 603-619.

I haven't checked if the paper describes estimate_bandwidth() too.